# Analytics vs AdWords E-Commerce Data - doesn't add up - Attribution?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking, google-ads

Adwords imports E-Commerce tracking from Analytics.

Under AdWords > All Campaigns > Conversion Value for a given period it says €7.004,70

For the same period in Analytics it says €7,912.97 under Acquisition > AdWords > Campaigns in the Ecommerce Revenue column.

Why is this different when the source is the same, being ga('ecommerce:addTransaction') data?

Is it related to attribution models? What is the default attribution model of AdWords and Analytics?

I would have thought AdWords might use an attribution model favouring AdWords, hence ending up being higher than Analytics, but it's the other way around here.

Where will I find the source of this discrepancy?

Comment: Does the analytics amount include shipping where the AdWords does not?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with this, it seems that Google Analytics e-commerce data includes shipping and/or sales tax.

Comment: Can you add a quotation of the important part of the linked content? That way if that link ever rots we still have the important information here.